# How to copy subsections multiple time in Azure Templates?

Tags: azure

I'm preparing a new Azure template using ARM and I would like to configure an inboundNatRules on loadBalancer for each VMs created. Number of VM is defined as parameters so I need to find a way to "copy" inboundNatRules section multiple time.

How can this be achieved? I'm going crazy on this one.

```
"inboundNatRules": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat('RDP-VM',copyIndex())]",                      
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendIPConfiguration":
                            {
                                "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
                            },
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "frontendPort": "[concat('227',copyIndex())]",
                        "backendPort": 22,
                        "enableFloatingIP": false
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to copy/clone NAT rules. However you can add custom script extension to the VM, that will execute powershell script which in turn creates the NAT rule for this particular vm:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat('MyCustomScriptExtension', copyindex())]",
    "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfInstances')]"
    },
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "dependsOn": [
       "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
       "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
       "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
       "settings": {
           "fileUris": ["http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/customscriptfiles/create-nat-rule.ps1"],
           "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File create-nat-rule.ps1",
            "protectedSettings": {
                "vmIndex": "[copyindex()]",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Content of create-nat-rule.ps1 file:

```
param(
  $vmIndex
)
$rdpPort = "5000$($vmIndex)" #port based on vm index: 50000, 50001, etc
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "DMZNSG" | `
Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name "Allow-rdp-vm-$($vmIndex)" `
    -Type Inbound `
    -Priority 120 `
    -Action Allow `
    -SourceAddressPrefix 'INTERNET'  `
    -SourcePortRange $rdpPort `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix '*' `
    -DestinationPortRange '3389' `
    -Protocol TCP
```

It is assumed that the load balancer exists prior to vm creation, if this is not the case you can simply add dependsOn to you vm definition or modify the powershell to create the load balancer if it does not exist

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to extract inboundNatRules now from load balancer resource, like that:

```
{
"apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/inboundNatRules",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('lbName'), '/', 'RDP-VM', copyIndex())]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "lbNatLoop",
    "count": "[variables('numberOfInstances')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', parameters('lbName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfiguration": {
      "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
    },
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "frontendPort": "[copyIndex(5000)]",
    "backendPort": 3389,
    "enableFloatingIP": false
  }
},
```

A really good example can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-natrules/azuredeploy.json